# Gnuplot - plot array over second array

Tags: gnuplot

I've been really struggling for a simple task. I have two arrays defined as such:

```
array dt[3] 
array e[3]
```

I would like to plot the values e with respect to dt. When I run. `plot dt, e`, I get:

```
[4.9999999999999e-11,1.00000000000001e-10,2.49999999999999e-10]
 [181128.855275673,212726.153802402,308803.296183617]
```

I know this is possible but I haven't found a single example online. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two forms of plot command possible.  The first is an implicit enumeration over elements of dt

```
plot dt using (dt[$1]):(e[$1]) with linespoints
```

The second is an explicit iteration used to generate samples for the pseudofile '+'

```
plot sample [i=1:|dt|:1]  '+' using (dt[i]) : (e[i]) with linespoints
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps a lot. Btw, what is this pseudofile '+' ? I've seen it used multiple times without really understanding what it does

Comment: Also, is it possible to add a fit to this plot ?

Comment: You can think of '+' as an artificial data source that provides a stream of numbers generated internally rather than being read from a disk.  An iteration like "for [i=1:100:2]" primes the generator to produce a sequence of numbers 1 3 5 7 ... 99.